# Remove a parent class from a child element before calling method on parent (javascript/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Say I have the following unordered list

```
<ul class="foo">
  <li>
    <div class="bar">
    </div>
    <div class="baz">
    </div> 
 </li>
 <li>
   <div class="bar">
   </div>
   <div class="baz">
   </div> 
 </li>
</ul>
<div class="nav">
    <a class="prev-link">Previous</a>
    <a class="next-link">Next</a>
</div>
```

I pass the list to a carousel like so `$(".foo").carouFredSel(//options)` however i don't want  the class `bar` to be affected by the carousel.

I've tried `$('.bar').removeClass('foo')` before calling the carousel, but it doesn't seem to work... it is still part of the carousel. How can i prevent that one div from inheriting the parent class or is there a different way I can prevent that div from being treated as part of the carousel i.e. (just left in place)?

Comment: The problem seems to be that .foo contains all of your divs, including .bar and .baz. If you only want to work with .baz, your carousel function will need to change to either exclude .bar divs or only use the .baz elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the !important CSS rule on the .bar class properties you don't want to overwrite. But that's probably not the best use of the rule.

You could also try :not() with the Foo class selector.

Comment: i don't want to not change properties of bar...i dont want bar to be selected when we select '.foo' ...can you say more about :not()?

Comment: Sure, there isn't a lot to it. Basically you can select an element that is not / or doesn't have a property. `.foo > div:not(.bar) {}` should select all the _div_ elements within class _foo_ who do not have the class of _bar_.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the class foo from your whole ul, if that's what you're going for.

```
$('.bar').parents('.foo').removeClass('foo');
```